# How to mirror file from remote server?

Tags: server, 20.04, ftp, wget

I tried wget

```
wget -m ftp://miljenko@lw001.usbx.me:11963/Mastering%20Chrome%20Developer%20Tools/
--2021-01-03 13:01:52--  ftp://miljenko@lw001.usbx.me:11963/Mastering%20Chrome%20Developer%20Tools/
           => ‘lw001.usbx.me:11963/Mastering Chrome Developer Tools/.listing’
Resolving lw001.usbx.me (lw001.usbx.me)... 185.38.14.145
Connecting to lw001.usbx.me (lw001.usbx.me)|185.38.14.145|:11963... connected.
Logging in as miljenko ... 
Login incorrect.
```

Then with lftp

```
lftp ftp://miljenko@lw001.usbx.me:11963/
Password: 
cd: Fatal error: Certificate verification: Not trusted (09:0E:0A:43:A8:C2:F7:E2:F6
```

My friend told me password,worked as a charm until now.

I tried what Matigo suggested

```
cd: Fatal error: Certificate verification: Not trusted (09:0E:0A:43:A8:C2:F7:A8:F6:F6:F4:E0:00:2C:E8:C7:EC:7E:FE:1A)
mirror: Access failed: 550 /Mastering%20Chrome%20Developer%20Tools: No such file or directory
```

1 error detected
Chrome dev tools
[image]

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to pass in some extra info for `lftp` if you want to avoid the `Certificate verification: Not trusted` issue. Try this:

```
lftp ftp://miljenko@lw001.usbx.me:11963 -e "set ftp:ssl-allow no; mirror -R ~/Downloads/ftp_out /Mastering%20Chrome%20Developer%20Tools; quit"
```

Be sure to set `~/Downloads/ftp_out` to whatever directory you want to download the contents to. The key element here, though, is `ftp:ssl-allow no`.

Another option would be to create a file named `~/.lftprc` and add the following line:

```
set ssl:verify-certificate false
```

If the `~/.lftprc` file already exists, just add the certificate verification bit above to the end.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I want to download from that server to my Downloads.